# Get HostName by IP Address Android

Tags: android

I'm making a simple IP Scanner in Android using Android Studio. I have successfully checked if the host is Alive or dead. But now I also need to get the hostname of a specific IP Address.

I tried the following two methods but they return Ip address not the hostname

```
InetAddress inetAddr;
    inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName(host.hostname);
    String hostname = inetAddr.getHostName();
    String canonicalHostname = inetAddr.getCanonicalHostName();
```

I also read on some forum to edit the host file, but that is not what I want.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: why don't you ask the DNS server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Resolve Network Host Names From IP Address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521844/how-to-resolve-network-host-names-from-ip-address)

Comment: @F43nd1r answers posted on that post doesn't work. it returns the ip address where as I am looking for hostname

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.example.com"); 
System.out.println(address.getHostAddress()); 
System.out.println(address.getHostName());
```

I hope this may help you.. :)

Comment: No this works only for the IP which is assigned to my machine, but if I type any other IP from my LAN than it just returns the IP Address