# How to get Host name of ip address in android?

Tags: java, android, networking, ip, hostname

I want to make a small android app that get ip addresses and host name from LAN network that are connected. I have a code that run great to get ip address in a LAN network which is connected but I don't know how to get host name of their ip addresses. Where I need to changing in code. Sorry for bad English.

> Here is my code for getting ip address in lan network

```
String connections = "";
    InetAddress host;
    try
    {
        host = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");
       byte[] ip = host.getAddress();
       for(int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
        {
            ip[3] = (byte) i;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);

            if(address.isReachable(100))
            {


                System.out.println(address + " machine is turned on and can be pinged "+address.getCanonicalHostName());
                connections+= address+"\n";
            }
            else if(!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
            {
                System.out.println(address + " machine is known in a DNS lookup");
                System.out.println(address.getHostAddress()+"host Name:"+ address.getHostName());
            }

        }
        tv.setText(connections);

    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what entries do you have in your hosts file

Comment: Look at this it will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521844/how-to-resolve-network-host-names-from-ip-address

Comment: Shreyas , i add this InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2").getHostName()
after opening your link but still give me same ip 192.168.1.2

Comment: no,  they give me the same ip that i passed in getByName method.

Comment: The hostname will be given by DNS Server.. to which DNS server are you connected to ?

Comment: i want to get hostname and ip address of all connected devices in my LAN network. If you know the exact code please post here.

Comment: the code is right, you have something called hosts file in windows/unix you need to assign a name for those ip addresses there.. do you know where to look for hosts file?

Comment: no. i don't know , please tell me , i need your help.

Comment: goto this link, follow the steps they have done.. until you can open the hosts file... once you open the hosts file.. just add in new line
192.168.1.1 Umar
then re-run the code you will see Umar

Comment: where is the link?

Comment: Sorry here it is: http://www.howtogeek.com/140576/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-android-and-block-web-sites/

Comment: sorry to say that i think you have not get my point. Let suppose i connect to a router  and my local ip address is 192.168.1.2 ,and 5 other people are also connect to that router and let suppose there ip address is 3,4,5,6 according to my ip address,  i just want to get these five people ip addresses and there names.

Comment: the link that you send it give me website's ips

Comment: if you have access to windows, goto C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and open hosts file. Add your ip address there give a space and then give a name. After that copy paste your code in eclipse and run.. you will understand what i am talking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .getHostname()

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");
String host = addr.getHostName();
System.out.println(host);
```

Comment: when I pass "192.168.1.4" it gives me same ip address that I passed "192.168.1.4".